# How can order of input attributes affect result of rendering?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Swapping order of two input variables corrupts rendering result. Why is that?

**Little info about it's usage:**

- vertexPosition_modelspace has location 0 and vertexColor has location 1
- I bind buffer storing vertex positions and set vertex attrib pointer, then I bind and set buffer for color

**Right one:**

```
#version 130

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
in vec3 vertexColor;
in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec3 fragmentColor;
// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){    

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

    // The color of each vertex will be interpolated
    // to produce the color of each fragment
    fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

[image: right order result]

**Wrong one:**

```
#version 130

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace; // <-- These are swapped.
in vec3 vertexColor;               // <--

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec3 fragmentColor;
// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){    

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

    // The color of each vertex will be interpolated
    // to produce the color of each fragment
    fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

[image]

Same problem is with texcoords and it took me hour to discover the problem. Why result gets corrupted if I put texcoord or color input after position? The order should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the order you use when you pass your data to shaders. In your OpenGL C or C++ code you are certainly sending the vertex color as the first vertex attrib, and then you send the position. If you intent to swap the order of parameters in the shader, you must swap the order of their initialization too.

Comment: Yes. I bind buffer and set pointer for position first(location=0) and then color(location=1). Why is order in shader opposite?

Comment: @Miro: Because you didn't force the compiler to put them into specific locations. Use `layout(location=…)` storage qualifiers to pin them down.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It pointed me in the right way. But it's not quite right. The problem was I linked program before specifying the attrib locations.